# Questions about chapter section and their formation

Tags: spacing, sectioning, formatting, chapters

[image: formats of chapter and section]

Hello, everyone, I want to arrange the chapter and section as the picture shown and The font should be Times New Roman, 12 point, could anyone give me some tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have an '11pt' document, which is default, this should be the solution:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont\centering\large}
{\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}}
{20pt}{\large}[\vspace{-1em}]

\let\oldchap\chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}[2][]{\oldchap[#1]{\MakeTextUppercase{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Remark: If your document is not '11pt', you have to change the `\large` calls in `\titleformat`.

**Output:**

[image: output]